# Applying consecutive transformations in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am a newbie to xslt and I have a variable "name" which stores a result of a transformation how can we transform the variable "name" using some other template in same xslt file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" >
      <xsl:variable name="name">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
          </xsl:copy> 
      </xsl:variable>
   </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns1:BP7Locations" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:Entry">
        <xsl:sort select="ns4:Location/ns4:LocationNum" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an example, you can consider this XML:

```
<root>
<a>value</a>
</root>
```

And this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="a">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="mode1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($a)/a" mode="mode2"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a" mode="mode1">
    <a><xsl:value-of select="'mode1 called'"/></a>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a" mode="mode2">
    <a><xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' mode2 called')"/></a>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the following as output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">mode1 called mode2 called</a>
```

The XSLT's first template has a variable `a` which stores the data after processing element `<a>` and then the `xsl:apply-templates` processes the data in the variable `a` again. Here the `@mode` on `xsl:template` differentiates the second and the third templates.

Answer (score 3):

In XSLT 2.0 the typical pattern for a multi-phase transformation is

```
<xsl:variable name="temp1">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="phase1"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="temp2">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$temp1" mode="phase2"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$temp2" mode="phase3"/>
```

In XSLT 1.0 this isn't allowed, because the variable holds a "result tree fragment" which can only be processed in very limited ways. Nearly every XSLT 1.0 processor implements the exslt:node-set() extension function so you can get around this restriction. The code then becomes:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp1">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="phase1"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="temp2">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($temp1)" mode="phase2"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($temp2)" mode="phase3"/>
```

You will need to add the namespace `xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"` to your stylesheet.

You don't have to use different modes for the different phases of processing, but it helps to avoid hard-to-spot bugs: the template rules for each processing phase should have corresponding mode attributes, and it can also be a good idea to put the rules for each mode in a separate stylesheet module.